# bottom menu android move to bottom

Tags: android

how problem in bottom menu android

[image]

xml code for activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framtab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomMenu2">

        </FrameLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/bottomMenu2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top">

            <include layout="@layout/bottom_menu"/>



        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

bottom menu android move to bottom

Answer (score 0):

try setting layout_height of your RelativeLayout from 50dp to wrap_content.
also bottom_menu layout might be the problem.

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framtab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomMenu2">

        </FrameLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/bottomMenu2"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:background="@drawable/white_grey_border_top">

            <include layout="@layout/bottom_menu"/>



        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: سلام زبانم داغونه و سوالم را نتونستم درست بپرسم.ببینید ابتدا مشکلی نداره و وقتی پایین میره که از فراگمنت فعلی به قبلی باز می گردم ،و وقتی بر می گردم باتم منو نصفش میره پایین و همون جا میمونه .اگر راه حلی میدونی ممنون میشم بفرمایید

Comment: کدی که گذاشتم رو امتحان کن

Comment: فرقی نکرد به آدرس زیر بیایید، فیلم گذاشتم از مشکل ممنون میشم ببینید و اگر راه حلی به ذهتنتون میرسه بفرمایید

Comment: http://p30droid.com/topic/7544-%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%B1-bottom-menu/#comment-28581